# is it possible to observe metrics changes on components without WidgetsBindingObserver mixin using GlobalKeys?

Tags: dart, flutter, observers

I'm writing an overlay package for flutter for tutorial walk-through.

In order to know which holes to make in the overlay to make the widgets behind it fully visible, the function requires a list of global keys and I use them to fetch location and size.

While the overlay is still visible, the widgets can be animated and move to a different location. Is there a way to detect that in order to re-draw the overlay?

I know that if I add a mixin of WidgetsBindingObserver to the widgets, I can check that with `didChangeMetrics()`. The problem is that I don't want the user to modify is original code. Is there a way to observe widgets metrics without changing their code?

My code is at https://github.com/kfirufk/tuxin_tutorial_overlay

Comment: see `WidgetsFlutterBinding`

Comment: and no, `didChangeMetrics` is called only if [Window](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Window-class.html)'s `devicePixelRatio`, `physicalSize`, `padding`, or `viewInsets` values change

Comment: @pskink - thank you for the info. unfortunately I'm a bit lost in the documentation. at first I thought that I need to add my widget to renderView.child and then add an observer... but apparently not. please provide more information. thank you

Comment: run this: `debugPrintBeginFrameBanner = true;
  debugPrintEndFrameBanner = true;
  var bindings = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  bindings.addPersistentFrameCallback((d) {
    print('persistentFrame at $d');
  });` and watch the logs - make sure you added some interactive widgets like button, checkbox  / whatever and interact with them

Comment: @pskink - persistentFrame is called whenever something changes in the ui. so should I manually check the previous location and new location of the widgets and if it changes to redraw? I though that there is some observable for that. (or did i misunderstand things again?)

Comment: `"while the overlay is still visible, the widgets can be animated and move to a different location. is there a way to detect that in order to re-draw the overlay?"` - you want to know when any widgets are animated, dont you?

Comment: @pskink - yeap :) I need to redraw the overlay only if specific widgets moved/resized not the all visible widgets on the screen. I assume that without adding the observable mixing to those widgets it's not possible. so this is a great solution. thanks :) please add it as an answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: @pskink - yeah :) testing it... so far looks really really awesome!!!!!! :) yay!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192761/discussion-between-ufk-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so thanks to @pskink amazing support I was able to properly resolve this issue.

I already have the Global Keys of the widgets I want to monitor for changes in size and position, so I don't need to drill down through all the widgets in the app.

so I'm adding a persistent frame callback and in there I check that that overlay being shown actually have holes to show widgets behind it, and if it doesת I use the `_sizeVisitor()` function to detect if any of the widgets position or size where modified, and if they where, I redraw the widget.

again.. thank you so much @pskink!

```
void _detectWidgetPositionNSizeChange() {
  var bindings = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  bindings.addPersistentFrameCallback((d) {
    if (visibleOverlayPage != null &&
        (visibleOverlayPage.disabledVisibleWidgetsCount +
                visibleOverlayPage.enabledVisibleWidgetsCount >
            0)) {
      for (final widgetGlobalKey in visibleOverlayPage.widgetsGlobalKeys) {
        if (_sizeVisitor(widgetGlobalKey)) {
          redrawCurrentOverlay();
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

bool _sizeVisitor(GlobalKey elementKey) {
  if (elementKey.currentContext != null) {
    final RenderBox renderBox = elementKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    bool isChanged = false;
    Rect newRect = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & renderBox.size;
    _rectMap.update(elementKey, (oldRect) {
      if (newRect != oldRect) {
        isChanged = true;
      }
      return newRect;
    }, ifAbsent: () => newRect);
    return isChanged;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```